# How to implement razorpay recurring payments in Android Studio?

Tags: android, payment-gateway, razorpay

I implemented razorpay payment gateway in my app, Now I want to provide a subscription payment option to my customers, So How do I implement a Subscription(Recurring payments) in Android Studio?

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 main steps:

Define a plan that sets what amount should be billed and how often.
Create a subscription for the selected plan with the start and end details.
Create an authentication transaction (auth transaction).
But, All of these three steps are to be implemented from the backend.

From the front end side (Android app) we need to do the following:

Need to fetch all the plan_id from the backend
Send the particular plan id for which we need the subscription and backend will generate a subscription_id.
Fetch the subscription_id created in the backend
During razorpay payment, add two extra parameters "subscription_id" & "recurring". Set recurring as 1.
Send the transaction_id to backend which we get on payment success.
FYI. I used the sdk "com.razorpay:checkout:1.4.5"